# MySQL second abstraction join slows query markedly

Tags: mysql, performance

When I add a second level of abstraction to a join, ie joining on a table that was join in the first place, the query time is be multiplied by 1000x

```
mysql> SELECT xxx.content.id, columns.stories.title, columns.stories.date
    -> FROM xxx.content
    -> LEFT JOIN columns.stories on  xxx.content.contentable_id = columns.stories.id
    -> WHERE columns.stories.title IS NOT NULL
    -> AND xxx.content.contentable_type = 'PublisherStory';
```

yields results in 0.01 seconds

```
mysql> SELECT xxx.content.id, columns.photos.id as pid, columns.stories.title, columns.stories.date
    -> FROM xxx.content
    -> LEFT JOIN columns.stories on  xxx.content.contentable_id = columns.stories.id
    -> LEFT JOIN columns.photos on  columns.stories.id = columns.photos.story_id
    -> WHERE columns.stories.title IS NOT NULL
    -> AND xxx.content.contentable_type = 'PublisherStory';
```

yields results in 14 seconds

this is being performed on tables with records in the 10ks to low 100ks of records

Is this normal or what could be causing such a slowdown?

first query plan:

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | content | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                 | 7099 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stories | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | xxx.content.contentable_id |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Second Query

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | content | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                 |  7099 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stories | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | xxx.content.contentable_id |     1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | photos  | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                 | 21239 |             |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: With performance issues, it's always best to post the query plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if joining columns.photos slows down so much, it could be because :
photos.story_id is not a foreign key from stories and  there is no index on that column.

Not seing your table structure, I could no tell exactly but I suggest you to
verify that photos.story_id is a foreign key and if your mysql version does not
support foreign key ( pretty old)  put an index on that column.

- I would check indexes on contentable_type and stories.title  also as they are
  part of the where  close.